# VueRouter: Child Component is not called

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

Hi guys I have the following route which I try to call different components that should load simultaneously using Nested Routes, I have a Navigational Bar (called NavBar) to be loaded together with my Main Form (called MainForm). Somehow the MainForm isn't called, only the NavBar. I also have a form with the absence of a NavBar hence the next route entry. The router contains the following code:

```
import MainForm from '@/components/MainForm';
import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar';
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'NavBar',
      component: NavBar,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/form/:id',
          component: MainForm
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/formNoNavBar/:id',
      component: MainForm
    }
   ]
});
```

On the first entry what happens is that the NavBar gets loaded by the app when I go to http://localhost:8080/#/form/sampleid but it doesn't load the MainForm. On the second entry, there are no problems loading the MainForm. What also further my doubts is that I added this to my MainForm.vue:

```
export default {
  name: 'MainForm',
  created: function () {
    console.log('heya');
  } ....
```

On the second route entry, "heya" displays on the console but on the first it doesn't. How do I fix the nested route I created to load both the NavBar and the MainForm vue files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how Vue nested route works. You think that a child route component can load an entirely different component from its parent route, right?

The parent route component should be a layout that encompasses the child route component. The parent route component should have `<router-view></router-view>` inside. `<router-view></router-view>` will be replaced by the child route component.

This is a pretty good example => https://codesandbox.io/s/qq8zk1n36. See `Layout.vue`